# Handling Future in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to read data from a function returned as Future object?

Please help with the below code:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> eventsQuery =  ref.where('idTo', isEqualTo: id)
                                        .where('isSeen', isEqualTo: 0)
                                        .getDocuments();

unReadCount = eventsQuery.documents.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your result, you need to `await` a future:

```
QuerySnapshot result = await eventsQuery;

unReadCount = result .documents.length;
```

This only works in `async` functions though.

For more information, check out the documentation: [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).

For Flutter, you can use the [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) class to simplify building widgets that rely on futures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.then` without the adding the `async`

```
ref.where('idTo', isEqualTo: id)
  .where('isSeen', isEqualTo: 0)
  .getDocuments()

  .then((result) {
    unReadCount = eventsQuery.documents.length;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the below code. The variable unReadCount always return intitial value as this run in an async way. How to solve this issue?

CollectionReference ref = Firestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .document(groupChatId)
          .collection(groupChatId);

```
   ref.where('idFrom', isEqualTo: id)
      .where('isSeen', isEqualTo: 0)
      .getDocuments()
      .then((result) {
    unReadCount = result.documents.length;
  });
```